# PHP: Problem in printing Arabic Characters in printer_write($handle, $string);

Tags: php, printing, arabic

I'm using `php_printer.dll` to auto print an order at specific kitchen in a restaurant. The problem is that the arabic characters in the printed receipts could not be shown in a proper way (ex.: Ø³ÙƒØ± Ø¨Ø§ÙƒØª) while the same printer can print different receipts using windows.print() without any problem and show arabic characters correctly.

Here is part from the code:

```
$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.1.105\\xp-80");'
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");'
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_RIGHT);'
'printer_start_doc($handle, "My Order");'
'printer_start_page($handle);'
'$rFont=printer_create_font("font-face", 20, 10, PRINTER_FW_MEDIUM, false, false, false, -50);'
'printer_select_font($handle, $rFont);'
'printer_write($handle, "بون تحضير ");'
'printer_write($handle, "\n");'
'printer_delete_font($rFont);'
'printer_end_page($handle);'
'printer_end_doc($handle);'
'printer_close($handle);'
```

Note: printer is xprinter-80 also I tried another one but I received the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arabicData="ون تحضير";
$EncodedArabicData= utf8_encode($arabicData);
```

And use the variable `$EncodedArabicData` when writing to printer, ie:

```
printer_write($handle, $EncodedArabicData);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but now it shows Chinese characters